# How to use 'this' keyword in function invocation pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand how to use 'this' in my Function Invocation. I have a function declaration, thats invoked in .ready(), but not on an object. I'm attempting to toggle visibility of the div directly next to a button with the '.btn_toggle' class. but ONLY the div thats next to the button thats pressed. not all divs next to all elements with class '.btn_toggle'. Most SO answers/references on topic are related to function invocations on an object, which i'm not doing

What i've attempted consists of listening for the click of any button with class '.btn_toggle'. and target the next element with jquery's .next(). it works, but toggles all div's next to a '.btn_toggle'.

```
jQuery ( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {

    toggleSubDiv(); 

});

function toggleSubDiv ( ) {
    var btn, target;

    btn = $( '.btn_toggle' );
    target = $( '.btn_toggle' ).next();

    // click listener on btn class 'btn_toggle'
    btn.click( function () {

    // toggle visibility
    target.toggle( );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `this` will refer to the clicked button inside the handler, simply wrap it in jQuery and call `.next` on it:

```
btn.click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: ahh i was using "this.next()". stupid. how would you *select* 'this' in the same context without jquery?

edit: how to *select* this

Comment: You'd have to iterate over all buttons and add a listener to each. `document.querySelectorAll('.btn_toggle').forEach((btn) => { btn.addEventListener('click', function() { /* add click functionality, this refers to btn */` (though, for the above, no need for `this` because you already have a reference to `btn` due to iteration)

Comment: The vanilla JS version of `.next()` is [`.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)